# Data missing from ByteArrayOutputStream after write operations

Tags: java, concatenation, bytearrayoutputstream

I'm trying to concatenate a series of `ByteArrayOutputStream` objects into a single one and I'm having trouble capturing all the data. For some reason only the first `write()` operation works (see code below), and the resulting `ByteArrayOutputStream` has a trimmed version of the data. I checked that the input list is intact (for instance if I reverse the order of concatenation the resulting object has data from the last element in the list).

Are there other function calls I need to make between the `write()` operations to make sure the byte arrays are actually copied? Thanks in advance!

```
ArrayList<ByteArrayOutputStream> outputStreams = new ArrayList<ByteArrayOutputStream>();
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStreamAggregate = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

// ... add data to outputStreams ...

for(int i = 0; i < outputStreams.size(); i++) {
    outputStreamAggregate.write(outputStreams.get(i).toByteArray());
}
```

Comment: call `flush` and `close` at the end.

Comment: Neither flush() nor close() is necessary in this case, and close() implies flush() anyway: you don't have to call them both. And this code is correct, so it is the input which must be incomplete. But ... Why do you have these ByteArrayOutputStreams at all? And why concatenate them into yet another one? You should be writing directly to the final output stream, instead of building up memory and latency like this.

Comment: @Jens I'm calling `outputStreamAggregate.close()` right after the for loop. Just added a call to `flush()`, same result though...

Comment: @EJP I'm actually writing the result to a `FileOutputStream`, I had a bunch of threads building the output streams and I'm combining them at the end

Comment: Why you do not use `writeTo(OutputStream out)` ?

Comment: @Cat You don't need to create two entire copies of the data to accomplish that.

Comment: Sounds like a multi-threading problem. You have to wait for the completion of all write operations before concatenating the results…

Comment: @Holger I'm using a `CountDownLatch` and `await()` to synchronize the threads, and the data seems to be recorded properly in the partial `ByteArrayOutputStream`s. If I log the size of each `ByteArrayOutputStream` I get different values (ex: 198204 bytes, 245991 bytes), but the final result always includes only the first byte array written.

Comment: Well, within the loop you have posted there is no error. So we have to trust you if you insist on the rest of your code being correct but I doubt that this will help you…

Comment: I figured out what was happening - the write operations worked, the problem is each stream contained an "end of file" character and when I was checking the final output I wouldn't get past that so I just assumed data was missing. The data was actually there, I should have checked the size of the output.